# Do you need a buffer for GET without Params?

Tags: asp.net, web-services, url, httprequest

If I'm making an OAuth Access Token request for resources of a third party Api I wraped, to get all customer cases data for example.

There are no querystrings required for this GET since I am just requesting data back, but my question is, do I still need to specify a request stream (byte data) of some sort or just assume that the ContentLength should be left out and is read as -1 by the Request object?

e.g. I don't have to worry about setting the ContentLength or buffer do I.  I just need to use a stream reader to grab the returned .json or whatever the API sends back to me correct?

```
        HttpWebResponse response;
        Stream dataStream; // data returned from the response
        byte[] buffer = null; // data to send in the request body

        // FYI the "data" variable is just an incoming param to my send method, a string if I want to send data in the request (i.e. json, xml, whatever I am sending if needed)
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(data.Trim())) buffer = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(data);

        // the resourceUrl variable I'm specifying for example is "ttp://someThirdPartyApi.com/api/v1/cases.json"
        HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest)WebRequest.Create(resourceUrl);

       // I then add an authorization header to the resonse.Headers (not shown here)

        request.ServicePoint.Expect100Continue = false;
        request.PreAuthenticate = true;

        // do we have any data to send in the request -body-??
        if (buffer != null && buffer.Any())
        {
            request.ContentLength = buffer.Length;

            using (Stream stream = request.GetRequestStream())
            {
                stream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
                stream.Close();
            }
        }

        // no data to send, just get the data returned in the response using a StreamReader
```

Comment: Did you try it? What happened?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unless you're actually posting data, you don't need to do anything with the request stream. Depending on what you're doing, you might even be able to use WebClient and its DownloadString() method, and avoid a lot of the extra code involved in using the lower-level WebRequest, etc.

Of course, you lose some control and flexibility, but maybe you don't need that if it's a simple API.

Comment: yea I'm trying to stay away from WebClient just because I never know what environments we may move this to.  I don't mind the extra overhead, I can create helpers or utility methods to clean that up and reuse.

Comment: What do you mean? Are you talking about migrating to Mono? Mono supports WebClient. There's no reason you couldn't use one or the other based on the environments you're in--it's just about which level of control you want, that's all.

Comment: yea there is no reason not to go with full control in case you need it.  Why design for something that has limits when you don't know if you might get hammered by those limitations later.  Always design for flexibility and in this case just a few more lines of code using an HttpWebRequest or using a stream to grab the data is just fine with me...it's not a big a deal to code a few more lines of code to make my application extensible in the long run so we don't have to possibly ever have to go back to refactor this.

Comment: Well, obviously it's your system and you can build it how you wish. My caution to you is that the downside to "full control" is that you have to write more code to support it, which means more time, more testing, more places it can break, and more time for someone to figure out what you were doing when they have to troubleshoot it 5 years from now. Sometimes it's ok, but it really is a lot more than just a few lines of code once you get into helpers and utility methods as you say. Again, it's up to you, I'm just trying to give you feedback about things that have bit me in the past :)

Comment: yep I don't mind it.  I'm a custom type of dude, I like patterns, I like clean.  I'm not saying I wouldn't use third party or plugings or shortcuts but this isn't a huge deal to just use the HttpWebRequest, it's only a few line of extra code man!  I mean common, we have to learn how to code, we can't as .NeT devs keep being hand held 100% on everything we do from Microsoft.  Look at Java Devs, they're not using stupid shitty Datasets, stuff like that.  THEY CODE.  I don't look for the first "easy out" when I code, I care about extensibility, clean code.  We've come accustomed to easy too much.

Comment: the argument is always more time to code, to test, etc.  That's why you have unit tests and practice clean code.  That's all part of development man.  Sorry I don't agree.  For those who always look for the excuse to always look for the easy way to do things, then if that's your mentality, that's fine, it's just not mine. I like good clean code, not always a "helper" from every source on the universe.  Use 3rd party frameworks where it makes sense and the underlying code better be damn clean and extensible IMO or move on.  The last thing good devs want to support is trash in the long run.

Comment: And using HttpWebRequest are fundamentals we all should be knowing as developers, how the web works.  It's not had to read that kind of code, you're simply sending a request....what's the big deal.  Other devs can't read it? common man, this is a simple HttpWebRequest!  give me a break.

Comment: My primary point was that you already have a built-in class that does everything you're trying to do, but you're building it from scratch yourself. No need to reinvent, when you could be building things that actually matter in your application. It's not that other devs CAN'T read it, it's that it will be custom code rather than standard library.